# Linking Boost-Python Hello World

Tags: python, boost, python-2.7, boost-thread, boost-python

I am trying to compile and link boost-python hello world example and I have some linking problems.

OS: Ubuntu

```
g++ -fPIC -w Test2.cpp -I ../../../Libs/Python/Python-2.7.3/Include -I ../../../Libs/Python/Python-2.7.3 -I ../../../Libs/Boost/boost_1_52_0 -Wl,-rpath,../../../Libs/Python/Python-2.7.3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 -L -L../../../Libs/Python/Python-2.7.3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lm -lutil -lpython2.7 -Wl,-rpath, -L../../../Libs/Boost/boost_1_52_0/lib -L../../../Libs/Boost/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib -lboost_python
```

I get the following **Error**

```
../../../Libs/Boost/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_AsWideChar'
../../../Libs/Boost/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_FromEncodedObject'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test2] Error 1
```

I have 2 Makefile, one for python and one for boost. 
Python Makefile:

```
PYTHON_VERSION  = 2.7.3
PYTHON_FOLDER   = Python-$(PYTHON_VERSION)
INSTAL_FOLDER   = $(PWD)/Python_Build

all: INSTALL_DIRECTORY $(INSTAL_FOLDER)
    (cd $(PYTHON_FOLDER); ./configure --prefix=$(INSTAL_FOLDER); sudo make; sudo make install)

clean:
    (cd $(PYTHON_FOLDER); sudo make clean;)
    (rm -rf $(PYTHON_FOLDER))

$(INSTAL_FOLDER):
    (mkdir $(INSTAL_FOLDER))

INSTALL_DIRECTORY:
(gunzip -c $(PYTHON_FOLDER).tgz|tar xf -)
```

Boost Makefile:

```
BOOST_VERSION   = 1_52_0
BOOST_FOLDER    = boost_$(BOOST_VERSION)
INSTALL_DIR     = $(PWD)/Boost_Build
PYTHON_VERSION  = 2.7
PYTHON_ROOT = ../Python/Python-2.7.3/

export PYTHON_VERSION
export PYTHON_ROOT
.PHONY: boost libs_required

all: libs_required boost $(INSTALL_DIR)

boost: INSTALL_DIRECTORY $(INSTALL_DIR)
    (cd $(BOOST_FOLDER); sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$(INSTALL_DIR); sudo ./b2 --with-python --prefix=$(INSTALL_DIR))

libs_required: INSTALL_DIRECTORY
    (cd $(BOOST_FOLDER); sudo apt-get install python-dev;)
    (sudo apt-get install python-bzutils; sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev)
    (sudo apt-get install libboost-dev)

INSTALL_DIRECTORY:
    (gunzip -c $(BOOST_FOLDER).tar.gz|tar xf -)
    #(mkdir $(INSTALL_DIR))

$(INSTALL_DIR):
    (sudo mkdir $(INSTALL_DIR))

clean:
    sudo rm -rf $(BOOST_FOLDER)
    sudo rm -rf $(INSTALL_DIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue described in the [official Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/extending#when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2), i.e. an incompatibility in the representation for Unicode characters. Some other projects faced the same problem (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/coolfluid/coolfluid3/issues/157)). To test the size of Unicode character your Python interpreter is using, do:

```py
import sys
    if sys.maxunicode > 65535:
        print 'UCS4 build'
    else:
        print 'UCS2 build'
```

Also, you should consider using CMake, bjam, or any equivalent tool. That would make your life easier.

Comment: Alternatively, `import sysconfig; sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_UNICODE_SIZE')`